# how to create ssrs report that shows database names as a dropdown filter and user can select the database dynamically and run the report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

how to create ssrs report that shows database names as a dropdown filter and user can select the database name and connect dynamically and run the report.

The Server name is same, just the databases must by dynamic.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a datasource in your report, this will not work on a shared datasource.

Create a new datasource and then next to the connection string field, click the `fx` button. You can build your connection string using parameter values to change the database. The expression might look something like this..

```
="Data Source=MyServerName;Initial Catalog=" & Parameters!myDatabaseParameter.Value & ";Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

Comment: HI Alan thanks for the response, I want the server name to be same, but within the server I want to change to different database

Comment: I've updated the answer, but basically you just need to swap out the part you want to change with your parameter value